# Alfresco: Handling special characters in PDF

Tags: special-characters, alfresco

The Requirement is: DITA(xml file) with special characters(Γ,Δ,Λ,Π etc) are uploaded to Alfresco. Componize has been used for pipeline configuration. I have used "DITAMAP to PDF(legacy PDF and FOP)" pipeline to generate the PDF out of Ditamap in which the special characters dita is referenced.  Those special characters are displayed as "#" in PDF. I need those special characters to be displayed in the generated PDF. Please suggest a solution to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A wild suggestion here, since I don't know what are your needs and all - but maybe you can integrate some outside function/software/service that alfresco could use?
I mean, setup some other software that will do the conversion correctly, and then just pass the ditamap to it from alfresco and have pick up the resulting pdf?